# Rails 3 - help with Atom Feed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Feel like I have been going around in circles, have followed different tutorials all proposing to achieve the promised result and none of them are working for me. I'm using the Kaminari plug-in and my articles are on the index page (6).Can anyone help me with this? Thx

application.html.rb

```
auto_discovery_link_tag(:atom) # =>
<link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="ATOM" href="http://www.currenthost.com" />
```

routes.rb

```
match '/feed' => 'articles#feed', :as => :feed, :defaults => { :format => 'atom' }
```

articles_controller.rb

```
def index
@articles = Article.published.page(params[:page]).per(6).ordered

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.atom  { @articles = Article.published }
  format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
end
end
```

articles/index.atom.builder

```
atom_feed do |feed|
feed.title "Title"
feed.updated(@articles.blank? ? Time.now : @articles.first.created_at)

@articles.each do |article|
feed.entry article do |entry|
entry.title article.title
entry.content article.body, :type => 'html'

entry.author do |author|
author.name article.author
end
end
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route goes to an action `feed` but your respond_to block corresponds to the action `index`. You probably want:

```
match '/feed' => 'articles#index', :as => :feed, :defaults => { :format => 'atom' }
```

Comment: In browser window it usually gives users the option to click on an RSS feed button. My app doesn't do that with the code listed above?

Comment: Is your link tag in the <head> of your layout erb?

Comment: Yes, its in the <head> tag. When I refresh the page on Safari it appears for 2 seconds then is replaced by 'reader'. On other websites they sit side-by-side normally

Comment: I've just noticed that the RSS button does stay in the URL bar on the Sign In page - when I click it the browser says "Safari can’t open the page “feed:http://localhost:3000/feed” because Safari can’t load any data from this location". So its not picking up the articles from that location?

Comment: @Felix - do you know of a good clear tutorial for an Atom or even RSS feed for rails 3 that takes into consideration pagination for articles on the index page?

Comment: Well, you can return any set of articles you want from pagination - I believe atom allows for links like /?page=2, where afterwards you could use your links. Also, looking at your code for your index action - change your format.atom to `format.atom { render :atom => @articles }`. Right now it isn't rendering anything at all, hence Safari's response - sorry I missed that earlier.

Answer (score 0):

In your application template (`application.html.rb`), try this instead:

```
<%= auto_discovery_link_tag(:atom, feed_path, { :title => "My ATOM Feed" }) %>
```

Comment: OK. When you load the (supposedly empty) page, view the source of the page (possibly through the right click menu, or the View menu, or something). Does an ATOM feed come up?

Comment: Also note that `@articles = Article.published` is not a good idea as it will show ALL published articles in the feed. Best to page this (you use a higher page size than the HTML output)

Comment: This displays in the source page which looks right to me *<link href="/articles" rel="alternate" title="My ATOM Feed" type="application/atom+xml" />*

Comment: But note that it points to `/articles` when it should point to `/feed` according to your routes.

Comment: Just do what @Felix suggested: replace what you have now (`format.atom  { @articles = Article.published }`) with `format.atom { render :atom => @articles }`